# Where does the Kafka JDBC Source Connector store the last read DB row?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to figure out, implementation-wise, how the Kafka Connect JDBC Source Connector keeps track of the last DB row it read and published. I found this page, which details in the second paragraph *what* they do, but not *how* they've done it: https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/overview.html#features

> Kafka Connect tracks the latest record it retrieved from each table, so it can start in the correct location on the next iteration (or in case of a crash). The source connector uses this functionality to only get updated rows from a table (or from the output of a custom query) on each iteration. Several modes are supported, each of which differs in how modified rows are detected.

I've been digging through this code, but haven't been able to figure it out just yet:
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/tree/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/source

I'm guessing they're storing the last published row in a DB/KV-store? Or perhaps there is a way to add metadata to the Kafka topic they're publishing to and then on the next interval it can poll it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, they publish to a separate topic to track the DB offset which they then consume from when the connector resets. More details in this section here:
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#resetting

And the source code related to this bit seems to be here: https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/storage/KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java